# Missing 'format_date' Twig filter in SonataNewsBundle

Tags: php, symfony-sonata, symfony-2.1

I've just installed SonataNewsBundle. I encounter this exception while trying to go _http://localhost/news:

```
The filter "format_date" does not exist. Did you mean "format_file" in SonataNewsBundle:Post:archive.html.twig at line 20
```

The question is what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `format_date` to `date` in archive.html.twig, view.html.twig, comment.html.twig and it's works

Comment: You need to use SonataIntlBundle: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/intl/master/doc/reference/installation.html